# Get subdirectory name in bat FOR /R loop and name file accordingly

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, batch-processing

I know this question sounds like a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer in all the similar questions.
I have this code in a .bat file:

```
  for /R "C:\Users\XX\XXX\XXXX\XY" %%F in (*.m*) do (
    ffmpeg -i %%F -vf "setpts=N/TB,fps=1,select=not(mod(n\,29)), crop=min(in_w\,in_h):min(in_w\,in_h), scale=1024:1024" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 -f image2 %%F-"frame-"%%3d.jpg
    )
```

Which takes every video file in the given path (C:\Users\XX\XXX\XXXX\XY), splits it into frames (every 29th frame) and saves those frames as "FILENAME-frame-FRAMENUMBER". This works very well, but I'd like to name the file "SUBDIRECTORY-frame-FRAMENUMBER". Is this possible? Every answer I read had the subdirectory name as its own variable (so in my case in place of the %%F), but I need that %%F to modify each file with FFMPEG.

I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Essentially what you want to search for is how to get the parent directory.  You can use another nested `FOR` command to do just that. `for %%G in ("%%~dpF\.") do set parent=%%~nxG`

Comment: Thank you! Now I have this: `for /R "C:\Users\jakra\Documents\denkbares\All_concepts_KFZ" %%F in (*.m*) do (
for %%G in ("%%~dpF\.") do set parent=%%~nxG 
ffmpeg -i %%F -vf "setpts=N/TB,fps=1,select=not(mod(n\,29)), crop=min(in_w\,in_h):min(in_w\,in_h), scale=1024:1024" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 -f image2 %parent%-"frame-"%%3d.jpg
)` but now I get the error message: "Unrecognized option 'frame-%3d.jpg'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found". So this interferes with ffmpeg's output argument. What can I do?

Comment: It looks like you are assuming no directory has more than one move file within it. Your results will be messed up if a directory has more than one source file. You might want to consider using both the parent directory name and the file name in your output name.

Comment: Ah, you're right, every folder has more than one video file in it, I've added the Filename as well. But for some reason, when I use `%parent%` in ffmpeg's output, like so: `%%F-%parent%-%%3d.jpg`, the value of parent doesn't get added to the filename. The resulting filename is still only "filename--framenumber.jpg". But in the console I see that %parent% has the correct foldername. Is my notation wrong?

Comment: You are inside a parenthesized code block.  So you have two options.  Nest the `FFMPEG` command in the second for command execution and use the `FOR` variable directly.  If you want to use the `PARENT` variable then you need to enable delayed expansion (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) and reference the variable with exclamation points. `!parent!`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It finally works. Bat is still very confusing for me, especially mixed with ffmpeg. I definitely learned something!